# How to auto fill username and password in shell script when prompt

Tags: shell

I want to add auto fill username and password when script prompt.

Here i want to fill username and password which is already in variable.

Here is my script please help me.

```
#!/bin/sh

my_user_id = "my_user_id"
my_password = "my_password"
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition

expect "Username:"
send "$my_user_id"
expect "Password:"
send "$my_password"
```

I want to automate my script.

Comment: Did you managed to solve this? I am running into the same issue. Tried several things, but no luck whatsoever.